# MS Access "Cannot connect to the SharePoint site" Error on Large Linked Lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I am having an issue with MS Access 2010 opening a large SharePoint linked list.  It was working fine on a Friday afternoon around 4:30pm, but then, the following Monday morning, I began getting an error when trying to open a large SharePoint linked list.  Not all of the linked lists, just the largest one, which has 8036 records (the view threshold is 10000).  MS Access appears to open the list,but then the wait cursor appears and then after some time an error message (Cannot connect to the SharePoint site '') displays and all of the displayed data is removed.

I've asked our sys admins if there were any group policy or system updates that were pushed and they were not aware of any (but that doesn't mean there weren't any).

Here is a screencast video of the problem that I am having:
https://youtu.be/_RYSmg-L0gc

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with SharePoint linked list, disconnecting them from Access and Linking anew. I have had mixed success with refresh link option in MS Access.